# UITests in Xcode 7: Unable to tap to Button on Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitest

If the buttons are always showed then it's fine. But my buttons are hidden and only showed up when tap on the cell. This is the sample project: [project source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7J8nMIupS79bTdzQUdhRF9EUWs/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

I tried different ways but no luck. Here is my code in UItest:

```
func testExample() {
    let firstCell = XCUIApplication().tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(0)
    firstCell.tap()
    let button = firstCell.buttons["hoang"] // Accessibility Identifier:hoang 
    if button.hittable {
        button.tap()
    }
}
```

Comment: In the screenshot your first cell is under the status bar. Could the problem be that the tap ends up on the status bar and not the cell?

Comment: I tried. It's not the problem.